# Show Mouse Cursor in Mobile - CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need your help because it works perfectly in desktop but in mobile the custom cursor in missing, how can i enable it thank you!

```
.logo-tiles-pencil {
    cursor: url(../img/logos/pencil-2.png) 10 3, auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In mobile you can't see the cursor, even you customize

Answer (score 0):

Cursors do not show up on mobile devices, because on mobile, you tap instead of moving a mouse a clicking

Answer (score 0):

The cursor on the mobile is not visible unless it uses a mobile simulator.